# Get current visible activity to user

Tags: android

I want to get the foreground activity running. And I am able to get this information by using activity manager by using following code.

```
activityManager = (ActivityManager) FWCommon.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
runningTaskInfoList = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
componentName = runningTaskInfoList.get(0).topActivity;
```

Suppose I have two activities A and B and i call this above code from onResume() of both activities A and B.

Following is the problem

1. When activity A starts above code gives me topActivity = A
2. Then I move from activity A to B and above code gives me topActivity = B
3. Then i press Back to move back from activity B to A and above code again gives me topActivity = B instead of A.

Thx
Dalvin

Comment: Sorry I have put a custom class code, consider the following code for getting the foreground activity. activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE); runningTaskInfoList = activityManager.getRunningTasks(1); componentName = runningTaskInfoList.get(0).topActivity;

Answer (score 9):

Try using getRunningAppProcesses() to get a list of RunningAppProcessInfo. Then go through each RunningAppProcessInfo and check if it is in the foreground by doing this:

```
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : processes)
{
    // Take a look at the IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE property as well in the link provided at the bottom
    if (process.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND)
    {
        // Put code here
    }
}
```

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html) for more information.

Comment: is there any way to check whether its on home screen ?