# Android - How to tell what Activities are currently open?

Tags: java, android

I'm falling into a bit of a dilemma. As I learn more and more about Android and Java, the more confused I am about the state of the building blocks of Android apps. (i.e. Activity, Service, Broadcast Recievers, Content Providers)

Since all of those building blocks are just Java classes, it's tough for me to wrap my head around them because there can be multiple instances of them. As of late the biggest challenge is with tracking which instance of the Activity is actually being created, started, resumed, etc;. I started playing around with Intent flags, and that just threw another wrench (or ten) into the equation.

Being able to tell their state would be indispensable and even better would be to see the current **task stack**/**process id** that the activity is associated with. At this point I'm just guessing whether or not FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP are working properly.

Surely there is a solution. Is there any debugging tool that I can use to get an inside view of my app/process to see which components (specifically Activities) are in existence?

---

Some notes/thoughts I've had:

1. Should I create a unique static auto-increment int for each class to try and track it myself?
2. Is this what I want [Get current visible activity to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881698/get-current-visible-activity-to-user/6881991#6881991)?
3. Does this application manually keep track or is it really peaking inside of the process? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode
4. There has to be a debugging tool for this... -__-

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will solve your understanding of the topic completely, but these guys did a nice app to try and visually see the main launch modes available for Activities > https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.novoda.demos.activitylaunchmode&hl=en_GB

Hope this helps in some way to explain things! :-)

Comment: This does not answer OP question.

Comment: OK. thanks for the positive feedback. I'm new to this question answering as you can see so just thought I'd try and lend a helping hand.  I'll try and be more specific next time, but I hope I might have helped a fellow traveler along the way in the mean time. :-)